# SQLLite howto join mutiple tables without column ambiguity

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I've the following simplified SQLLite query:

```
SELECT SPECIALTABLE.DETAILS AS Details 
FROM SPECIALTABLE 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERTABLE 
ON CUSTOMERTABLE.CUSCODE = SPECIALTABLE.CUSCODE 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERNAMETABLE 
ON CUSTOMERNAMETABLE.NAMECODE = CUSTOMERTABLE.NAMECODE 
WHERE NAMECODE LIKE '%' LIMIT 10
```

SPECIALTABLE does not contain the NAMECODE column.

But when I run the query, it gives the "ambiguous column name" error on NAMECODE. I do not want to specify the table however on namecode (e.g. WHERE CUSTOMERTABLE.NAMECODE LIKE ...).

To my understanding, SQLLite should treat the result of these joins like one big table containing all columns that are contained in each of the tables, so why is there ambiguity?

The problem is there is no column directly linking SPECIALTABLE and CUSTOMERNAMETABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write your last line, you do not specify what NAMECODE is in condition. So, the SQL can't catch the NAMECODE correctly, because there is two definitions for them (`CUSTOMERNAMETABLE.NAMECODE` and `CUSTOMERTABLE.NAMECODE`)

```
WHERE NAMECODE LIKE '%' LIMIT 10
```

Try to Specify the Table that you want the NAMECODE condition, like this:

```
WHERE CUSTOMERNAMETABLE.NAMECODE LIKE '%' LIMIT 10
```

Or this:

```
WHERE CUSTOMERTABLE.NAMECODE LIKE '%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: But is there not a way to make one definition for NAMECODE?

Comment: Anytime you JOIN tables, if you select a column name that exists in more than one of the tables you must prefix it with the table name. If you Want to both columns NAMECODE, just duplicate the condition:
`WHERE CUSTOMERNAMETABLE.NAMECODE LIKE '%' LIMIT 10 
AND CUSTOMERTABLE.NAMECODE LIKE '%' LIMIT 10 `

Comment: I tried that, but the strange thing is: it gives an empty result. That why I wanted to circumvent the table prefix.

Comment: Can you post the content of the tables? To a better view of the situation. The "ambiguous column name error" is fixed by a prefix, but maybe you're using the wrong condition to get the desirable output.

Comment: No I can't, sorry. But I did it exactly like you said, with the prefix in both tables. So you are saying that this should work indeed?

Comment: When you use LIKE '%' you have to specify the pattern you want to find. What are you looking for? It's hard to see when i do not now what are you trying to find with that statement. Can you tell me what output you desire?
For example: `WHERE CUSTOMERNAMETABLE.NAMECODE LIKE '%code%' LIMIT 10`

Comment: '%' should return all data from that column, but it will change to something else, lets say NAMECODE LIKE 'ABC'. But that should make no technical difference though

Comment: If you want all data, you don't need to use LIKE. Just use the LIMIT, to define the number of the results. If you comment the conditions, the output still empty?

Comment: No, then it is not empty, but with a single prefix column where statement it is not empty either.

Comment: Update: it seems that it is working now also with two where statements using prefixes. I do not know where it went wrong at the first. Thanks for your help though. But to be clear: it is not possible to make the join in such a way that a prefix is not needed?

Comment: See these examples and try to adapte to your code. Try use %namecode% with a namecode that you now that will return you something.
`WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'` Finds any values that start with "a"

`WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'` Finds any values that end with "a"

`WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%` Finds any values that have "or" in any position`

Comment: Glad that Work out. Unfortunately, you have to specify the prefix, to SQL understand what are you looking for.